# C# Adding controls to a non-static form from a static class

Tags: c#, xml, controls

In C#.NET, I am trying to add controls from a static class to a non-static class.

This is my code:

```
    public static void AddMediaToPanel(string Title, string Description, string Source, string Cover, string Genre, int Rating)
    {
        PictureBox MediaCanvas = new PictureBox();
        MediaCanvas.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        MediaCanvas.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        MediaCanvas.Size = new Size(150, 235);
        MediaCanvas.Padding = new Padding(10);

        try
        {
            MediaCanvas.ImageLocation = Source;
        }
        catch { }

        var gui = new GUI();
        gui.Controls.Add(MediaCanvas);
    }
```

The `GUI` method stands for a Windows Form called 'GUI'.
I'm trying to make an open-source media center that allows you to add movies
to a repository.

The static void `AddMediaToPanel` must be static, because of this class:

```
    public static void RetrieveMedia(string XMLFile)
    {
        // Declare the Media Collections
        MediaCollection media = null;

        // Declare the XML-readers
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MediaCollection));
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(XMLFile);
        try
        {
            media = (MediaCollection)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The following media repository could not be loaded:\n" +
                            XMLFile + "\n" +
                            "Please check your code and try again later.\n\n" +
                            "Error Information: " + ex.Message, "Repository error",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

        // Create new instance of the media class
        sr.Close();

        // Return properties
        try
        {
            foreach (Video video in media.Video)
            {
                GUI.AddMediaToPanel(video.Title, video.Description, video.Source, video.Cover, video.Genre, video.Rating);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.2.
Thanks in advance!

~ Kees van V.

Comment: And your problem is ?

Comment: Well the second part of your code is not a class as stated, it's a method. Now why is this method static ? We don't know. And that's probably something you can do another way. And you should probably start here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I removed the static part and now I can finally add controls to my GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't work this way.  In your loop you are calling your static method:

```
foreach (Video video in media.Video)
{
    GUI.AddMediaToPanel(video.Title, video.Description, video.Source, video.Cover, video.Genre, video.Rating);
}
```

But your static method creates a new `Form` each time, adds a control to it, then throw it away:

```
var gui = new GUI();
gui.Controls.Add(MediaCanvas);
```

You need to create your form once (outside of your static method), then have your static method *return* a control that you can add to your single `Form` instance.

Your instance method with the loop could look like:

```
var gui = new GUI();
foreach (Video video in media.Video)
{
     var control = GUI.AddMediaToPanel(video.Title, video.Description, video.Source, video.Cover, video.Genre, video.Rating);
     gui.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you just create and throw away the `gui` form:

```
   var gui = new GUI();
   gui.Controls.Add(MediaCanvas);
```

You have to *find* the form instance you want the controls be added to:

```
   public static GUI CurrentGui {
     get {
       GUI gui = Application
        .OpenForms
        .OfType<GUI>()
        .LastOrDefault();

       // no such form found, you may want to create the form 
       if (null == gui) {
         gui = new GUI();
         gui.Show(); // <- let's show it up
       }

       return gui;
     }
   } 

   ...      

   public static void AddMediaToPanel(...) {
     ...
     CurrentGui.Add(MediaCanvas);
   }
```

Comment: Really? I never used this method before, but maybe this is a lot better than creating a simple variable.

Comment: @Kees van V. When having a variable you have to syncronize its value with the form (what if the form has been closed? re-create again? just has been hid?). Searching is easier (give me the last opened form of `GUI` type)